# Excel string data graph

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, xls

I have an Excel xls sheet in which I have a column with string values in each cell. In each cell, there are many words separated by a comma. My plan is to rearrange this sheet so to create a new column in which each cell has only one word, from the preceding column. In this way I will sort in alphabetical order the new column, to count how many times a word repeats, then,I will make a chart of the most repeated words. But I don't know the workflow to get to this goal. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- Highlight the column that contains your list.
- Go to Data > Text to Columns.
- Choose Delimited.
- Click Next
- Choose Comma.
- Click Next.
- Choose General or Text, whichever you prefer.
- Leave Destination as is, or choose another column. 
- Click Finish.
```

Comment: I wanted to put everything in a column, make new rows with each word, instead, i created a lot of columns horizontally, and what i wanted was only one column with all observation vertically. I explained it wrongly sorry. Any suggestions are welcome.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you please upload some sample data or the whole spreadsheet?

Comment: Actually ive found out how, using your recommendation, i just added one more step: after everything is on columns, I just copy all the data and paste it using transpose in a new sheet or blank space...